# Execute a PySide6.QtCore.Qt.Key

Tags: pyqt, pyside, pyside6

I have a process that receives multiple Qt.Key s. Is there a way to execute these keys programmatically?

I tried using pyautogui:

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.press(Qt.Key_A)
```

and pynput:

```
import pynput
keyboard_controller = pynput.keyboard.Controller()
keyboard_controller.press(Qt.Key.Key_F1)
```

None of them works.

Comment: Why do you want to use Qt enums? AFAIK, nor pyautogui or pyinput accept it, so you should use those functions based on the implementations of those modules: see [`KEYBOARD_KEYS`](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#keyboard-keys) for pyautogui or the [pynput documentation](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#controlling-the-keyboard).

Answer (score 0):

I created a dictionary like so:

```
MAPPED_KEYS = {
        16777216: Key.esc,
        16777217: Key.tab,
        16777219: Key.backspace,
        16777222: Key.insert,
        16777223: Key.delete,
        16777224: Key.pause,
        ...
    }
```

And then I just used

```
MAPPED_KEYS.get(keycode, None)
```

To get the correct pynput key